# Simultaneous requests with uWSGI / Nginx

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

My flask server responds to requests one at a time. Is it possible to make it respond to e.g. 8 requests at a time?

For reference, my configuration is below:

`app.ini` for uWSGI

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
chdir = /app
module = app:app
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /run/uwsgiApp.sock
pidfile = /run/.pid
processes = 4
threads = 2
enable-threads = true
```

`nginx.conf` for nginx

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /dev/stdout info;

events {
    worker_connections  20000;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile    40000;

http {
    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip off;

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.com;

        location / { try_files $uri @flaskApp; }
        location @flaskApp {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgiApp.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

`entrypoint.sh` for Docker container

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running app in production mode!"
nginx && uwsgi --ini /app.ini --master
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN cat /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
    RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules
RUN apk update

# basic flask environment
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git nginx uwsgi uwsgi-python3 \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install flask

# For uWSGI
RUN apk add linux-headers

# expose web server ports
EXPOSE 80

# application folder
ENV APP_DIR /app

# app dir
RUN mkdir ${APP_DIR} \
    && chown -R nginx:nginx ${APP_DIR} \
    && chmod 777 /run/ -R \
    && chmod 777 /root/ -R
VOLUME ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# copy config files into filesystem
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY app.ini /app.ini
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# execute start up script
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`app.py` for Flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = False

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'hello world'
```

Comment: You should be using 1 Nginx container as a reverse proxy in front of 4 different flask container instances, if I understand the question correctly

Comment: @cricket_007 didn't consider that. Is there a way to do it without 4 different containers, i.e. have a single flask container handle multiple requests simultaneously?

Comment: @cricket_007 Would a 4 container setup look like 1 container for the nginx + 4 containers for the flask + (not in the original question) 1 container for redis for caching and celery?

Comment: Well, that's 6 containers in total, but yes. Each Flask container processes as many requests as it can independently. Nginx (though I might recommend that you look at Traefik instead), will route traffic evenly across each instance.